# Not able to use Log.* After importing from android.util.Log

Tags: android, logging

I am not able use Log.* After importing from **android.util.Log**

```
package com.example.readcpptwo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    private static final String TAG = "myFirstApp";

   Log.e(TAG,"MainActivity"); // **Log.e** is not recognize 

 }
```

Things tired so far are :

1.Auto Import Settings : **There is empty qualified name mask**

2.Tired google no help.

3.Android studio version 3.5.3 for Windows 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Move **log.e()** line inside **onCreate()**

```
Log.e(TAG,"MainActivity");
```